# Where is swift compiler's symbol table?

Tags: compiler-construction, name-lookup, symbol-table, swift-compiler

I wanted to know how name resolution happens in swift compiler, but I am unable to find code that is responsible for name lookup.

A explanation of how name lookup happens (in swift compiler) will be a huge help.

I also suspect that name lookup is done in `AST::DeclContext` class, but I am not sure.

Edit:
Please try to use c++ (If you add any code snippet), as I am not much familiar with swift, but you can add little bit of swift also :).

Comment: What bearing does this question have with `c++`?

Comment: It's still not obviously a question *about* C++.

Comment: Ahh, I presume the context of the question is the LLVM compiler itself, which is in C++.  (Or at least the part in the context of the question is written in C++.)  You may have better/faster response on the LLVM forums: https://discourse.llvm.org/

Comment: @Eljay swift compiler uses LLVM, but the name resolution is done in the swift compiler. That is why this question is not LLVM specific. Anyway, thanks for trying to help :)